# visual c# to visual basic encoded

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to coded in visual basic .net (v. 2008) the next API written in C#.
How should it be in visual basic?

```
private static string UrlEncode(string url)
    {
        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder(url.Length * 2);
        string unreservedChars = String.Concat(ValidUrlCharacters, ValidPathCharacters);
        foreach (char symbol in System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url))
        {
            if (unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
            {
                encoded.Append(symbol);
            }
            else
            {
                encoded.Append("%").Append(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
            }
        }
        return encoded.ToString();
    }
```

I've tried the next code  but it doesn't work. It is not returning the character and it can not be found in the string unreservedChars.

The code works in C#.

```
Private Shared Function UrlEncode(ByVal url As String) As String
        Dim encoded As New StringBuilder(url.Length * 2)
        Dim unreservedChars As String = String.Concat(ValidUrlCharacters, ValidPathCharacters)

        For Each Symbol As String In System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url)
            If unreservedChars.IndexOf(Symbol) <> -1 Then
                encoded.Append(Symbol)
            Else
                encoded.Append("%").Append(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", CInt(Symbol)))
            End If
        Next

        Return encoded.ToString()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your VB version - you used 'String' as the iteration variable instead of 'Char', and instead of 'CInt' you should use 'AscW' to go from 'Char' to 'Integer':

```
Private Shared Function UrlEncode(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim encoded As New StringBuilder(url.Length * 2)
    Dim unreservedChars As String = String.Concat(ValidUrlCharacters, ValidPathCharacters)
    For Each bytesymbol As Byte In System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url)
        Dim symbol As Char = ChrW(bytesymbol)
        If unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) <> -1 Then
            encoded.Append(symbol)
        Else
            encoded.Append("%").Append(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", AscW(symbol)))
        End If
    Next bytesymbol
    Return encoded.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: 'Byte' values cannot be converted to 'Char'. Use 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW' to interpret a numeric value as a Unicode character or first convert it to 'String' to produce a digit.

Comment: Ok - makes sense - I've updated my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 3):

You should get rid of that entirely and call `Uri.EscapeUriString` or `Uri.EscapeDataString`, depending on what you actually want.

Comment: Wow - you are a star!  In 2 minutes you came up with a more concise alternative to the problem (it took me that long to just read it!).